# Angular 2+ floating video

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I wanted to make my video player to float as the way I see CNN and Youtube on scroll. So that player will always be visible to the user. My question is how can I detect when the scroll reaches my video player?
If it is possible in Angular 4
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution for this? Looking for the same thing and would love to hear how you accomplished this.

Answer (score 0):

I also want to do that i havent done that yet but my idea is very easy if you are good coder you can create it easly

First we create iframe container(any div) with default position(Relative) class then when user clicks on the video we will store the player index in variable and when user scrolls down we simply make the player iframe container positive:Fixed we can swipe the classes  and we can also store the scroll position of video so when user comes back in we simple again swite class from fix to relative and video will be on its place without stoping